# How to make an sql query that combines values across multiple columns into a single one in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have the following:

```
swim_names, football_names, soccer_names, swim_age
John, Johnny, Johnson, 5
Mike, Michael, Mike, 2
Jo, Joe, Joey, 7
```

How can I construct an SQL query such that I can get the following output below:

```
names, age
John, 5
Johnny, null
Johnson, null
Mike, 2
Michael, null
Mike, null
Jo, 7
Joe, null
Joey, null
```

Note that:

1. names are distict names across all three of the "_names" columns
2. swim_age is available only for the names in "swim_names"

Comment: you can use 'group by swim_names'?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Your question title is not clearly illustrated in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `UNION ALL` like:

```
 SELECT swim_names as Names, swim_age as age FROM tbl
 UNION ALL
 SELECT football_names as Names, null as age FROM tbl
 UNION ALL
 SELECT soccer_names as Names, null as age FROM tbl
```